# Перевести cp855 в utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8

Подскажите, как на php преобразовать кодировку cp855 в utf-8.
Пытался через `utf8_encode` и получал знаки вопроса.
Через `iconv`, на что получал ошибку, что cp855 неизвестная кодировка.

Comment: Думаю тут проблема не относится к PHP, а больше к настройкам серверного окружения, где будет выполняться этот скрипт.  Вероятней всего решается добавлением соответствующей кодовой страницы. Если у вас действительно данные на сербском или болгарском языке  - ищите варианты как добавить эту кодовую страницу на ваш сервер.

Comment: а вы попробуйте вместо cp855 - cp866. и потом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706077/php-convert-windows-1251-to-utf-8